# Confirmation page before finalising order in CartThrob?

Tags: cartthrob

Is it possible to create a confirmation page prior to the finalising the order in CartThrob?

The idea would be that the customer would enter in their billing/shipping details. Then a page will be shown with all of their billing/shipping details, alongside an overview of the order, asking them to confirm everything is correct. At this point, they could then enter the payment details to finalise the order, or go back to edit any details if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course.

You can output anything relating to the cart contents using the `{exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}` tag pair, and output anything relating to the user's personal details (including shipping info etc) using the `{exp:cartthrob:customer_info}` tag pair.

If you have any custom data held against the customer, you can fetch this with `{custom_data:your_var_name}` (having previously set it inside the `save_customer_info` form).

Then after all that just include `{exp:cartthrob:checkout_form}` tag pair somewhere to allow for final checkout.